# jQuery.FilterTable: Return alert when no results found

Tags: jquery

I found this nice [jquery plugin](http://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/) to filter table results on the clientside.

It works absolute fine, but I would like to return an alert when there are no matches.
The jquery can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sunnywalker/jQuery.FilterTable/master/jquery.filtertable.js).

As you can see there are some comments:

```
     } // if the functionality should be added
    }); // return this.each
}; // $.fn.filterTable
```

But I need a little help on this..

**UPDATE**

```
if(!tbody.find('td').hasClass(settings.highlightClass)) 
  $('#planner-data').html("<div class='alert alert-info alert-dismissible geen-resultaten-filter' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>Geen opdrachten gevonden!</div>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the function where the filtering is done, I've commented in the section where you will want to loop through the results to determine if there are no matches and show your alert.

```
var doFiltering = function(table, q) { // handle the actual table filtering
            var tbody=table.find('tbody'); // cache the tbody element
            if (q==='') { // if the filtering query is blank
                tbody.find('tr').show().addClass(settings.visibleClass); // show all rows
                tbody.find('td').removeClass(settings.highlightClass); // remove the row highlight from all cells
                if (settings.hideTFootOnFilter) { // show footer if the setting was specified
                    table.find('tfoot').show();
                }

            } else { // if the filter query is not blank
                tbody.find('tr').hide().removeClass(settings.visibleClass); // hide all rows, assuming none were found
                if (settings.hideTFootOnFilter) { // hide footer if the setting was specified
                    table.find('tfoot').hide();
                }
                tbody.find('td').removeClass(settings.highlightClass).filter(':filterTableFind("'+q.replace(/(['"])/g,'\\$1')+'")').addClass(settings.highlightClass).closest('tr').show().addClass(settings.visibleClass); // highlight (class=alt) only the cells that match the query and show their rows

                // ****************************************************
                // Check to see if any items in the table are visible
                // if NO ITEMS are visible THEN show your alert
                // ****************************************************

            }

            if (settings.callback) { // call the callback function
                settings.callback(q, table);
            }
        }; // doFiltering()
```

**EDIT**

This should do the trick -

```
if(!tbody.find('td').hasClass('alt')) 
    alert('no results!');
```

**In my opinion**

> An alert is not the ideal way of letting the user know there are no results. An alert popping up all the time is not user friendly. Instead I'd recommend implementing something like this:

```
if(!tbody.find('td').hasClass(settings.highlightClass)) {
    $('body').find('#empty').text('No results').show();
} else {
    $('body').find('#empty').hide();
}
```

Where you've added some element with an id of `empty` right below your table that can display a message when there are no results from the filter:

```
</table>
<p id="empty"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please provide me a little more help..? My jquery knowledge is quite limited.. And something else.. Is there a way to exclude the first and the last <td> from the filter?

Comment: Update about the excluding.. Is this the right way:`tbody.find('td').not('td:first-child, td:last-child').removeClass(settings.highlightClass).filter(':filterTableFind("'+q.replace(/(['"])/g,'\\$1')+'")').addClass(settings.highlightClass).closest('tr').show().addClass(settings.visibleClass);`?

Comment: The excluding of the first and last `<td>` works as it should now, but I still can't get the filter to show an alert when no results are found.. Could you please help me a little further? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried your code in the place where you putted the comments. I replace the js alert for a bootstrap alert (see my updated answer). But somehow it doesn't always works as it should.. For example: when I have a `<td>` with the word 'test' and I type 'tes' it already shows the alert.. But with other words this behaviour doesn't take place.. And when I clear the input the alert is still shown.. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @JK87 I've added another section to my answer to give you what I think will be a cleaner solution and avoid unnecessary alert pop-ups

Comment: I tried your code and it almost works fine :) though, when I type something that triggers the 'No results `<p>`' and I backspace the word at once (due selection) or hold backspace to clear the input, it shows my results again, but underneath them it still says 'No results'.. This behaviour doesn't happen when I repeatly hit backspace.

Comment: Can you post what your code looks like? The jsfiddle I had wasn't having any of these issues.

Comment: And the bootstrap alert what I mentioned earlier isn't actually a pop-up alert as you can see here: [ Bootstrap alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts). My table-results are injected in `<div id="planner-data"></div>` I would like to return the bootstrap alert (in my updated answer) in that `<div>` as well (without the `<th>`'s. I also think that it would be nicer to keep the alerts in the `jquery.filtertable.js` file instead of an empty `<p>` tag under the `</table>`. Do you think that's possible too?

Comment: You still need a container of some sort to display your alert on the page (whether that's a <div> <p> or <block> is completely up to you) it's just a matter of hiding it and showing it at the right times. Make sure your code is in the right place like in my example.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't respond for such a long time..! Everything works fine now. The problem that the 'No results' text stays visible when I hold backspace, could be fixed with `$(".filter-opdrachten").keyup(function() {
                     if (!this.value) {
                      $('#empty').hide();
                     }
                 });` Thanks for all your help! :)